# How can I inform to my sqs polling that my spot ec2 in going to terminated in next two minutes?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, autoscaling

How can I inform to my sqs polling that my ec2 in going to terminated in next two minutes ?

I have used sqs and autos calling group, my sqs simple queue pooling request for ce2. ec2 takes task request from sqs and excute.

problem scenario : as i used spot ece aws terminate ec2 to manage capacity. now i want to stop new task execution over ec2 once it got termination request from autos calling or from aws.

How can I deal with it?

Comment: I noticed that you have a number of questions with answers, yet not a single answer was accepted. Its OK, if they were not helpful, in that case a comment would be warranted to let the person making the answer that it does not work. But if the answers were helpful, accepting them is not only good practice, but it removes your question from [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tab=Unanswered&tagMode=Watched) list, which is a big help.

Comment: Is the polling happening inside the instance or outside?  If inside, have the application check the local metadata every 10 or 15 seconds to see if there's a spot notification.  If outside use CWE as Marcin mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would setup **CloudWatch Event (CWE) rule**:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "EC2 Spot Instance Interruption Warning"
  ]
}
```

The CWE rule would trigger a **lambda function**, and the function could perform a number of actions on your instance, depending on what you want to do. This is use-case and application specific, and depends how your app gets notified about such events and what it does.

It could, for example:

- use **SSM Run Command** to execute a bash/powershell commands on your instance to do cleaning before termination occurs.
- it could call **http endpoint** on your instance which is exposed by your application. This way your application can directly get notified that it is going to be terminated soon.
- **copy** some logs or data files to s3 before it gets terminated
- and more